# Запятая в ССП перед союзом "и", когда оба подлежащих обозначают одно и то же

Tags: пунктуация, ссп

Нужна ли запятая перед союзом "и" в следующем предложении:

**На сегодняшний день (название компании) является признанным мировым лидером в области искусственного восстановления зрения, и в (дата) Компания также получила разрешение на проведение клинических испытаний новейшего импланта.**

Answer (score 1):

Это обычное сложносочиненное предложение (ССП) — значит запятая нужна, так требуют правила.
У каждого из простых предложений есть свои подлежащее и сказуемое, и не имеет значения, как подлежащие связаны между собой по смыслу (это может быть даже одно и то же слово).

С точки зрения стиля, слово "также" кажется мне лишним (ведь испытания  импланта - это тоже из области искусственного восстановления зрения)